# VBA Excel Problem Using an Array of Custom Classes in a Custom Class

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, class, oop

This is frustrating. I feel I am doing something stupid but can't nail it, so any help appreciated. I am of course a novice so I expect I am making a fundamental error.

Issue is:

I have created two apparently simple Custom Classes. The first defines a record of five fields (String, Integer and Currency) The second, defines an Array of the Record Objects defined in the first Class and adds a few simple reference fields. (String etc, nothing complex)

I have a simple test program. It first declares an Array of Records (50), then creates all the objects by "Set...= New" in a For Loop in the Initialize Sub. So far so (apparently) good.

The Test code writes 3 (garbage) records to the Array. After experimenting the Test sequence is now: Add a Record to the Array (Locations (0) to (2)). Retrieve a record from  **Location (0)** (Which shouldn't change but does) immediately after each Add and print the result.
After all three have been written, the results are again printed for **all three locations**, using a For...Next loop. The results are shown in the debug.print output below:

```
 Record 0   A nice Bunch of Flowers     Bunch of Flowers    1   20  
 Record 1   A nsdfgh of Flowers         Bunch of Fgfffwers  4   23345  
 Record 2   A nsdf3 Also Flowers        BunchThirds         4   23345   

 Record 2   A nsdf3 Also Flowers        BunchThirds         4   23345   
 Record 2   A nsdf3 Also Flowers        BunchThirds         4   23345  
 Record 2   A nsdf3 Also Flowers        BunchThirds         4   23345`
```

i.e. It **Seems** that - If re-read at the time of writing the record can be retrieved.  - As soon as a further record is written, all  records in the Array up to the highest one written become the latest and (not shown above) If I try to read records above (2) they are empty.

What am I doing wrong? It looks as though my latest write to the Array is always being written to all locations to which I have previously written instead of just the one addressed.

The relevant code is:

In the Array Class Declarations:

```
Dim intSize As Integer 'The currently declared size of the Array
Dim trrRec(50) As clsTransRecord 'Shown hard coded to 50 here for test.
```

In The Array Class Initialization:

```
Private Sub Class_Initialize()

Dim l As Integer 'Counter

intSize = 50 'The currently declared size of the Array

'Create the Objects
'==================
For l = 0 To intSize
Set trrRec(l) = New clsTransRecord
Next l

End Sub
```

In the Test Code: (Loads Three Records with dummy data and then Adds them to the Array)

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim trcTest As clsTransRecord
Dim trcTest2 As clsTransRecord

Set trcTest = New clsTransRecord
Set trcTest2 = New clsTransRecord

Dim j As Integer

Dim traTest As clsTransArray
Set traTest = New clsTransArray

trcTest.LoadRecord "Record 0", "Bunch of Flowers", "A nice Bunch of Flowers", 1, 20
traTest.AddRecord trcTest

Set trcTest2 = traTest.GetRecordAccount(0)
Debug.Print trcTest2.TrCat, trcTest2.TrDesc, trcTest2.TrItem, trcTest2.TrTransDay, trcTest2.TrValue

trcTest.LoadRecord "Record 1", "Bunch of Fgfffwers", "A nsdfgh of Flowers", 4, 23345
traTest.AddRecord trcTest

Set trcTest2 = traTest.GetRecordAccount(0)
Debug.Print trcTest2.TrCat, trcTest2.TrDesc, trcTest2.TrItem, trcTest2.TrTransDay, trcTest2.TrValue

trcTest.LoadRecord "Record 2", "BunchThirds", "A nsdf3 Also Flowers", 4, 23345
traTest.AddRecord trcTest

Set trcTest2 = traTest.GetRecordAccount(0)
Debug.Print trcTest2.TrCat, trcTest2.TrDesc, trcTest2.TrItem, trcTest2.TrTransDay, trcTest2.TrValue

Debug.Print

For j = 0 To 5
Set trcTest2 = traTest.GetRecordAccount(j)
Debug.Print trcTest2.TrCat, trcTest2.TrDesc, trcTest2.TrItem, trcTest2.TrTransDay, trcTest2.TrValue

Next

End Sub
```

The AddRecord Sub is:

```
Public Sub AddRecord(clsNewRcd As clsTransRecord)

intRcdCnt = intRcdCnt + 1 'Increment the Record Counter
'Write the Record
'================
Set trrRec(intRcdCnt - 1) = clsNewRcd

End Sub
```

And the GetRecordAccount Function is:

```
'Gets an individual Record from the Object.
Public Function GetRecordAccount(k As Integer) As clsTransRecord

Set GetRecordAccount = trrRec(k)

End Function
```

clsTransRecord code is shown below: The entries relate to Bank Records and Descriptions

Declarations:

```
 'clsTransRecord Variables

 Private strCat As String '- Category of Transaction. Allows Grouping of Items. Not always used
 Private strItem As String '- Describes the Item as it appears in the Budget Entry or Bank Statement. Used to compare Budheted to Actual
 'so can be difficult to read due to strange Bank Statements
 Private strDesc As String '- The longer, uderstandable, version of the Item Description.
 Private intTransDay As Integer '- The day of the month on which the transaction occurs
 Private curValue As Currency '- The Value of the Transaction. Positive for Income, Negative for Expenditure.
```

The clsTransRecord Class LoadRecord Code is

```
 Public Sub LoadRecord(strRecCat As String, strRecItem As String, strRecDesc As String, intRecTransDay As Integer, curRecValue As Currency)

 'Loads an individual Record

 strCat = strRecCat 'Record Category
 strItem = strRecItem 'Short Item Budget or Statement description.
 strDesc = strRecDesc 'Full Description of Item
 intTransDay = intRecTransDay 'Day on which the transaction happened/will happen
 curValue = curRecValue 'Value of the Transaction

 End Sub
```

The Initialize Sub for the clsTransRecord is below.

```
 Private Sub Class_Initialize()
 'Clears everything

 strCat = "" '- Category of Transaction.
 strItem = "" '- Describes the Item as it appears in the Budget Entry or Bank Statement
 strDesc = "" '- The longer, uderstandable, version of the Item Description.
 intTransDay = 0 '- The day of the month on which the transaction occurs
 curValue = 0 '- The Value of the Transaction

 End Sub
```

Comment: Where did you declare `intRcdCnt`?

Comment: You need to show the code for load record.

Comment: intRcdCnt is declared with other similar variables at the head of the clsTransArray Class.

Comment: Sorry for the slightly truncated response above. Getting to know the system. RE. Freeflow question the code for LoadRecord will be above in about 10 minutes I hope..Rgds and Thanks to you both..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you change the same instance of the record named `trcTest`. You add this instance and change it again etc. So you just *add and change the same location in memory every time*. Therefore you have same results.

If you need three instances, then you need to create three instances, e.g. something like this. HTH

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

' Array wrapper
Dim traTest As clsTransArray
Set traTest = New clsTransArray

' New records
Dim trcTest0 As clsTransRecord
Dim trcTest1 As clsTransRecord
Dim trcTest2 As clsTransRecord

' Record for print
Dim trcTestPrint As clsTransRecord

Set trcTest0 = New clsTransRecord
Set trcTest1 = New clsTransRecord
Set trcTest2 = New clsTransRecord

' Firts record
trcTest0.LoadRecord "Record 0", "Bunch of Flowers", "A nice Bunch of Flowers", 1, 20
traTest.AddRecord trcTest0

Set trcTestPrint = traTest.GetRecordAccount(0)
Debug.Print trcTestPrint.TrCat, trcTestPrint.TrDesc, trcTestPrint.TrItem, trcTestPrint.TrTransDay, trcTestPrint.TrValue

' Second record
trcTest1.LoadRecord "Record 1", "Bunch of Fgfffwers", "A nsdfgh of Flowers", 4, 23345
traTest.AddRecord trcTest1

Set trcTestPrint = traTest.GetRecordAccount(1)
Debug.Print trcTestPrint.TrCat, trcTestPrint.TrDesc, trcTestPrint.TrItem, trcTestPrint.TrTransDay, trcTestPrint.TrValue

' Third record
trcTest2.LoadRecord "Record 2", "BunchThirds", "A nsdf3 Also Flowers", 4, 23345
traTest.AddRecord trcTest2

Set trcTestPrint = traTest.GetRecordAccount(2)
Debug.Print trcTestPrint.TrCat, trcTestPrint.TrDesc, trcTestPrint.TrItem, trcTestPrint.TrTransDay, trcTestPrint.TrValue

Debug.Print

Dim j As Integer
For j = 0 To 5
Set trcTestPrint = traTest.GetRecordAccount(j)
Debug.Print trcTestPrint.TrCat, trcTestPrint.TrDesc, trcTestPrint.TrItem, trcTestPrint.TrTransDay, trcTestPrint.TrValue

Next

End Sub
```